# Where does the term "3D girl" come from?

Tags: terminology

When people (usually otaku) talk about real girls, they always refer them as "3D girls". I guess it's kind of opposite from "2D girls" in anime, manga, games, etc.

So, where did the term "3D girl" come from? What is its origin?

Comment: I hate to sound rude, but isn't the answer to this essentially just the dictionary definition of 2D and 3D?

Comment: @Ataraxia that's why I'm asking about the origin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2d girls are called as such because they are portrayed through screens, pages and other flat surfaces. Even when made into figurines and other items they are still usually referred to their main medium.

Note that computer generated characters like in Knights of Sidonia are usually treated as 2d persons because of their medium, despite being 3d.

Girls are called 3d by otaku (often derogatory) when they talk about girls in the real world - where there is a concept of 'depth', a third dimension.
Again the term 3d girl is used when they are depicted in photographs or similar, because we reside and interact with these people in a 3d world.

Otaku who prefer 2d women occasionally offensively use the phrase '3DPD', or "3d, pig disgusting"

[image]

2d girl vs 3d girl.

I don't believe there is an 'origin' for this, as dimensions are facts and this difference has always existed. However, the term has probably picked up usage with the rise of the internet and raised  popularity of anime